# Eclipse class folder changing to default folder after restart

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having little trouble resetting my eclipse class folder to a custom class folder after every restart/refresh of eclipse. Because eclipse resets the class folder for the project to a default folder **'/project_name/project_namebuilds'**(which does not exist). How can i resolve this issue?